# Can't find iPhoto on my Mac OSX system

Tags: macos, iphoto

Mac OSX: I can't find iPhoto.

I can't download any pictures anywhere.  I thought iPhoto came with OSX but not all applications.

Can I get iPhoto?  Should I look for another application to do the same?  I'm not familiar with Apple, and am older.  Advice/suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Just to be sure, check that iLife really isn't on your system by searching with spotlight (by clicking the magnifying glass icon in the top right corner) for 'iphoto.' After that, check your 'Applications' folder, and just scan through. 
If it really isn't there, locate the DVD's that came with the Mac. They should usually be in a pouch in the box the Mac came in. One of the DVD's should be labelled 'Applications Install DVD.' Place in your Mac's disc drive, and follow instructions to 'Install bundled software.' After you finish, iPhoto should be installed. 
iPhoto really should have come on your Mac already, and you should not have had to do anything about it to get it going. This may have been a slip in standards or an error at the factory, because usually Apple products are delivered in perfect as-advertised condition. 
Hope this helps.

(Apologies if I came across as patronising, but I tried to be as clear as possible if you are new to Apple :) )

Answer (score 1):

iPhoto is part of the [iLife Software Bundle](http://www.apple.com/ilife/) and usually preinstalled on newly sold Macs. Check the DVDs that came with your unit where one of them says "iLife".

Comment: The personal attack on the poster really isn't warranted. The first part of your answer is helpful, the second part really isn't.

Comment: @GAThrawn: done.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with the iPhoto icon, you can go to Finder, which will open by default in your Home folder, and then go to Pictures. If you see 'iPhoto Library' and it picture with a palm tree and camera, iPhoto is still installed and recognized. If it isn't, the application has been deleted.

If it is indeed gone, you can, as Alistair Maxwell mentions, the Applications DVD will allow you to reinstall the iLife suite.

Failing everything else, or if you're not quite confident, you can take it to a local Apple Store where they'll reinstall iLife or recover your current application at no cost.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a legal copy of iPhoto, you can buy it. It's part of iLife, but if you wait until tomorrow (6 January) when the Mac App Store opens, they will probably be selling iPhoto on it's own for a lower price.

Also, you don't need iPhoto just for downloading pictures from your camera. The Image Capture utility that's part of OS X will also do the job.

Answer (score 0):

My macbook air was missing iPhoto and the others (Garage band and iMovie), it may have been 'lost' after I upgraded my iOS to Mountain Lion - so I went to the Mac App store and downloaded iPhoto for free!